# How to fix unsupported format error in OpenCV without changing the data type of the input image every time?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, types

In the code below, I am trying to implement thresholding but I need to change the data type of the image (numpy array) for every type of threshold, since I was getting an error.

```
a = cv.threshold(img.astype('uint8'), 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
b = cv.threshold(img.astype('uint8'), 0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

The error is something like this,

`OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1659: error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)  in function 'cv::threshold'`

Is there any way to fix this without getting an error each time a function in opencv is ran and the format that is used is an unsupported one?

Edit:
Code snippet is added to clearly explain the context of the problem

```
img = np.load(i).astype('i')
img += 1024    # Since the min intensity value of the img is -1024, adding it would make all pixels to fall in the range of whole numbers
img = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(gimg, in_range='image', out_range=(0, 255))
a = cv.threshold(img.astype('uint8'), 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
b = cv.threshold(img.astype('uint8'), 0, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Comment: Did you load image with `cv.imread()`? If you did, it should work with both methods. If not, please share how you loaded image.

Comment: No, the input images are CT slices which are in **.npy** format and are loaded using `np.load()`. The max and min pixel values are -1024 and 2388 which are normalized to 0 and 255.

Comment: Did you try to use `img.astype(np.uint8)` in both methods? As I am aware, both methods use `uint8`, don't see where you need `float32`.

Comment: You are passing the image here as a float32, even though the threshold function is expecting uint8. Is your error on this line or the next one? `a = cv.threshold(img.astype('float32'), 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]`

Comment: @MilosStojanovic sorry for that thing it is uint8 not float32. I will edit that.

Comment: So it's not that straightforward :). How did you normalize array? Did you check if there are some values in array that are not same type or not in desired range?

Comment: I checked the max and min of the array and normalized using `skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity()` method.

Comment: So in normalized array, there are only unsigned integers in range [0, 255]?

Comment: They are of type int32. So, I am coverting them into uint8 so that I won't get any error. But I want to know if there is any way so that the input image is directly typecasted into a format suitable for the method. I can't just change the type of the element everytime I use a new method because of an error regarding the incompatible type.

Comment: So you want to load image in specific type (in this case, `uint8` because you need it for these methods) so you don't have to manually change types in the rest of the program? Also, if everything works when you change type to `uint8` (as I understand, you are not getting error when you change it's type?) why can't you just make new variable that will be array of new type?

Comment: "Is there any way to fix this without getting an error " -- sure, call it with an array of supported type. Hard to give you any more concrete advice, when instead of a proper [mcve] you provided 2 lines of code torn out of context.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic the thing is if there are other methods that accept input in some format other that `uint8`, I need to type cast my input data again to use it in those methods. So, I want to know if there is anyway by which the typecasting part is automatically taken care of or atleast any other easy way to do it instead of me typecasting it all the time.

Comment: @DanMašek I have added proper code snippet so that you can clearly understand what I meant. I want a way to typecast the input data so that it is compatible with the method that I am using it in without me typecasting it every time.

Comment: So, for example, you have variable of `type1`, you have three methods that accept arguments of types `type2`, `type3`, `type4`. Methods don't typecast their own arguments by themselves so you have to do it. Also methods are not generic so that won't work too. Only way I see is that you typecast it evey time you call some of the methods or that you make new variables that are of types that methods accept and then you just pass them when you need to call methods.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic Yeah I wanted to know that. My question is answered by this.

Comment: Ok, glad to be of some service. Since we wrote a lot in comments and people don't really read comments as much as answers, if my answer is satisfactory, consider marking it as such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, as I understand it, problem is that methods need `numpy` array containing `uint8` values and you have `int32`. So you have to change it's type using `array.astype(np.uint8)` so that you can pass it as argument to methods. If you want to do it only once, just make new variable that will contain array of new type.

Now, if you want to load image as `uint8`, that you may or may not be able to do, considering restrictions of library and of data format that you are using for storing image.

**[Edit]**
Final answer:
So, for example, you have variable of `type1`, you have three methods that accept arguments of types `type2`, `type3`, `type4`. Methods don't typecast their own arguments by themselves so you have to do it. Also methods are not generic so that won't work too. Only way I see is that you typecast it every time you call some of the methods or that you make new variables that are of types that methods accept and then you just pass them when you need to call methods.